# KDS -- Error in final launch sequence

Tags: c, embedded

I am using Kinetis Design Studio v 3.0 and am trying to launch a C application on my FRDM-K64 board. The project builds just fine; however, when I try to debug, I get this error:

```
Error in final launch sequence
    Failed to execute MI command:
    -exec-run
Error message from debugger back end:
Don't know how to run.  Try "help target".
Don't know how to run.  Try "help target".
```

I haven't a clue why this is happening. Other projects (such as the "bubble" example) launch just fine, and I am using basically the same launch configuration. I'm using Segger J-Link, although I tried using OpenOCD as well and got the same message. Any ideas of how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem--apparently my software needed to be updated. So if anyone is getting the same error, be sure you have tried checking for updates.